# How can I avoid down-votes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes, jsfiddle

I think [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879851/is-p-element-block-level) is fair, but the person who answered it has down-voted me. Why?

Is it because I didn't write proper code in the question, and gave a direct link to view it instead? Should I provide all my code in the question instead of a link?

Comment: After having a quick glance at your question, I would say the issue is that your problem is not immediately clear. Code and pictures of how the result looks and how you want it to look like would have been helpful.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Just a note - you can't really know that the downvoter was the same person who answered the question.

Comment: To follow from what @Hannele said, it's actually fairly unlikely that the person who answered also downvoted - if they thought it was worth answering, they wouldn't object to the question.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question here (and it's already answered if you research the archives), it should be something in the lines: [*How can I improve my Question?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aimprove+title%3Aquestion).

Comment: Why are you rolling back good edits?

Comment: I would like to remove my question link.

Comment: @user2253835 - Then this question would not help future users. So going to vote to close as *too localized*.

Comment: Oh! okey then edit my question with the link please.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all - put all the necessary information in your question and not in an external link. Links can break and the question is useless.

After that you should put some effort in your question: Explain what you want to achieve, what you tried and where you are stuck. All that takes more than a one-liner.

In some comments people asked for clarification. But you did not response to that. The first minutes after you ask a question are the most important ones. Stay put. Answer to comments. Clarify what is necessary. Edit your question to make it better and clearer.

Comment: I think I was down voted coz I edited my question properly but din't response for clarification.

Comment: Your edits were not that big actually. You did not even include what you want to do. You left a comment 45 minutes after asking that you are trying to center images but did not bother to include that in the question.

Comment: Your question is closed now. But that is not the end of the world. Improve it and flag it for reopening when you are done. A moderator will look at it and if fine you can receive answers again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep on mind of these things.

Comment: Why is this question also down voted?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: You can say that you improved your question and would like it to be reopened.

Answer (score 10):

Because by looking at the question I have no idea of what you are talking about.

Questions should be **self-contained**. You should include the **relevant** code in your question and include the images of what is expected to happen in the question. Everything should be there. The fiddle is just something to help people *play* with your problem. It should not be the only representation of it.

---

By relevant, I mean exactly what @KenWhite pointed out. We don't want to have 1000 lines of code. You should normally be able to reduce the code to a snippet of 50 or fewer lines. This way, the problem is easier to understand AND shows that you tried to isolate the problem properly. Trying to solve the problem yourself is part of the research to make a good question.

Comment: +1, but I'd change "include the code" to "include the **relevant** code". Otherwise, you'll start getting 1000 line posts of code that's added to a question about an error on a single line. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Well said! I've edited!

Comment: @KenWhite "start"? I do of course agree with your comment. =)